# How to access parameters from action delegate and pass to another method in case of exception?

Tags: c#, delegates

I have 2 derived types :

1) AggregateCalculator

2) AdditionCalculator

Each of the above derived types have different `transformation logic for subvariants` and basically there are 2 steps involved in this process :

1) Tranform

2) Create and store version

If there is any error in step 2 then remove data from steps 2 of current `Left and Right Subvariant`.

I have kept common code in VariantProcessor in order to share between above 2 derived types  but now the problem is am facing is that, If there is error then how do I pass current `Left and Right subvariant Id to the DeleteStatistics method`.

If I take `Left and Right Subvariant as instance field at class level` then it wont be required for my below method :

```
StatisticsModel Process(List<Subvariants> subvariants);
```

DeleteStatistics method for AdditionCalculator also require Left and Right SubvariantId in order to delete statistics for step1.

**Code :**

```
public interface IVariantProcessor
{
    void Process(Variant model);
    StatisticsModel Process(List<Subvariants> subvariants);
}

public class Variant
{
    public int VariantId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Subvariants> Subvariants { get; set; }
}

public class Subvariants
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public sealed class VariantProcessor
{
    private string _myAppConnectionString { get; set; }
    private readonly Action _transform;
    private readonly Action _deleteStep1Data;

    public Variant(string _myAppConnectionString,Action transform, Action deleteStep1Data)
    {
         _myAppConnectionString = _myAppConnectionString;
        _transform = transform;
        _deleteStep1Data = deleteStep1Data;
    }

    public void Process(Variant model)
    {
        try
        {
            _transform();
             //version creation shared by both the derived types
        }
        catch (Exception) 
        {
          _deleteStep1Data();//How to pass currently executing left and right subvariants if to this method ?
        }
    }
}

public class AggregateCalculator : IVariantProcessor
{
    private string _myAppConnectionString { get; set; }

    public StatisticsModel Process(List<Subvariants> subvariants)
    {
         //other logic
        //_myAppConnectionString is not needed for this code
    }


    public void Process(Variant model)
        {
            _myAppConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            new VariantProcessor( _myAppConnectionString,
               () => Transform(model),
               () => DeleteStep1Data(model.VariantId));
        }

    private void Transform(Variant model)
    {
         for (int counter = 0; counter < model.Subvariants.Count - 1; counter++)
            {
                var left = model.Subvariants[counter];
                var right = model.Subvariants[counter + 1];
                //some sort of transformation process between left and right
            }
    }
    private void DeleteStep1Data(int variantId,int leftSubvariantId,int rightSubvariantId)
    {
        VariantRepo.DeleteStatistics(variantId,leftSubvariantId,rightSubvariantId);
    }
}
```

So is is possible to access this left and right subvariants Id parameters from Action delegate or Is there any other way around ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [Action delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action) encapsulates a method that has no parameters and does not return a value. That means there are no parameters to access.

When you pass this as argument of type `Action`:

```
() => Transform(model)
```

...you're not passing an `Action<Variant>`. That is, you're not passing a method that takes an argument of type `Variant`.

You're passing an `Action` which represents an anonymous method with *no parameters*. That's what `()` means. If there were parameters they would be inside those parenthesis. The *body* of that anonymous method is a call to a method with a parameter.

The code that receives that `Action` doesn't know what is in that method. It just executes it. It doesn't know the difference between

```
() => Transform(model)
```

and

```
() => {} // does nothing
```

Another way of describing it is that by passing an argument of type `Action` you've hidden the body of the method represented by the `Action`. It could be anything. It could be multiple statements - pretty much anything that would go inside of a method. This is exactly what you would do if you *didn't* want to expose what was going on inside the `Action`.

If you wanted both the parameter *and* a method to invoke using that parameter, then instead of passing an argument of type `Action` you could pass two arguments:

```
Variant variant, Action<Variant> action
```

Now you've got the parameter (a `Variant`) and a method you can pass it to (an `Action<Variant>`). You would call `action(variant)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and for your kind efforts towards helping me but as you can see that I have list of subvariants inside variant object and at a time I execute 2 subvariants.Now lets say I have 3 subvariants in my Subvariants list and If i have got error in 2-3 then I want to remove data for 2nd and 3rd subvariants id so how to get that subvariant id in _deleteStep1Data method ?

Comment: That part is a bit difficult to follow. It might be easier to step back and look at it from the perspective of what the code needs to accomplish and going from there vs. trying to work some extra behavior into the way it's already implemented. Is that the same question or perhaps something different?

Comment: Sorry, you sent me a chat and then I closed the window. It's a little bit hard to get down to that level, though. Most of the time I try to answer through questions. Plus if you ask a new question you might get someone else's really awesome answer. (I love Stack Overflow too!)

Comment: Actually I was having a problem with passing action delegate as argument with model and for that I have ask a question and indeed got a nice answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166139/argument-error-while-passing-action-delegate-as-parameter-to-constructor) but still thank you so much for your kind help :)