# Argument error while passing Action delegate as parameter to constructor

Tags: c#, delegates

I am trying to pass Action delegate with to constructor but getting below error :

> Delegate 'Action' does not take 0 arguments

**Code :**

```
public sealed class VariantProcessor
{
    private string _myAppConnectionString { get; set; }
    private readonly Action<Variant> _transform;
    public Variant(string _myAppConnectionString,Action<Variant> transform)
    {
         _myAppConnectionString = _myAppConnectionString;
         _transform = transform;
    }
    public void Process(Variant model)
    {
        try
        {
            _transform(model);
             //version creation shared by both the derived types
        }
        catch (Exception) 
        {
        }
    }
}

public class AggregateCalculator : IVariantProcessor
{
    private string _myAppConnectionString { get; set; }
     public void Process(Variant model)
     {
            _myAppConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            new VariantProcessor( _myAppConnectionString,
               () => Transform(model) //error
               );
     }
    private void Transform(Variant model)
    {
        //logic on variant model
    }
}
```

I tried like this as well but still no luck :

```
new VariantProcessor(_myAppConnectionString,
                   Transform(model) // error
                    );
```

Actually I have problem understanding this syntax `() => Transform(model)` hence I am not getting whats the problem here.

Can someone please help me figuring out whats the problem here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Action` that your constructor takes is a `Action<Variant>` which means it is a piece of code that takes a single parameter of type `Variant` and returns void (because an `Action` doesn't return anything.

When you call the constructor you can either pass it a lambda that takes a single parameter like this:

```
new VariantProcessor(_myAppConnectionString, model => Transform(model));
```

or you can pass it the name of a function that takes a `Variant` and returns `void`:

```
new VariantProcessor(_myAppConnectionString, Transform);
```

The syntax:

```
() => Transform(model)
```

means a lambda that takes zero parameters (that's that the `()`) means. You need to supply a lambda that takes a single parameter. You can write it either as:

```
model => Transform(model)
```

or

```
(model) => Transform(model)
```

When you've got a lambda that takes more than one parameter then you have to put them inside brackets.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me and very nice answer and explanation.Very nice.When i do like this : Transform then How does delegate takes Variant model as parameter because with the method I have not specified anything

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow- I don't understand the question? You've got a delegate that takes a parameter.

Comment: Yes i got it.Do you think it would make sense to make Action delegate to accept generic parameter instead of concrete class?

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow- No, you've got it right, it needs to take an class.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following code. You requires to pass an argument in lemda

```
public class AggregateCalculator : IVariantProcessor
{
    private string _myAppConnectionString { get; set; }
     public void Process(Variant model)
     {
            _myAppConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            new VariantProcessor( _myAppConnectionString,
               (o) => Transform(model)
               );
     }
    private void Transform(Variant model)
    {
        //logic on variant model
    }
}
```